# Firefox crashes when I open Gmail after upgrading to 14.10

Tags: firefox, 14.10, gmail

Every time I open Gmail Firefox crashes, unless I open it in basic HTML mode. There are a few other websites that make it crash, and I'll try to name them here every time a website makes it crash. I have already submitted a bug report to mozilla.

Please help, I want to chat with my friends.